# Google Map Api v2 not showing any map

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, authentication

i still cant get my maps to show on my device
i just created a new map activity with Android studio , and followed the on screen instruction but still im getting the same error.
i didnt touch the mapActivity.java at all

--update--
same thing happen when i started a new a project

AndroidManifest.xml (i tried to replace gms with V2 and still nothing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ofir.bopofinal">

    <!-- google maps permission -->
    <!-- Required -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.ofir.bopofinal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.ofir.bopofinal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- Optional -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <activity android:name=".CreateNewEvent.CreateNewEventActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginRegister.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginRegister.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Categories.SuggestCategoryActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainAppScreenActivity" />

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".CreateNewEvent.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.ofir.bopofinal.CreateNewEvent.CreateNewEventActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>




12-08 13:30:36.283 17880-18426/com.example.ofir.bopofinal E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
12-08 13:30:36.283 17880-18426/com.example.ofir.bopofinal E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-08 13:30:36.286 17880-18426/com.example.ofir.bopofinal E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                     Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                     Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                        API Key: AIzaSyBlUuFCU_rpmxVq8x0V5KzFugnM6Yo43Uw
                                                                                        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): A8:A2:BE:67:AA:2F:C6:A2:BA:40:58:C9:D7:41:38:D0:98:B6:DA:42;com.example.ofir.bopofinal
12-08 13:30:37.813 17880-18420/com.example.ofir.bopofinal W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
12-08 13:30:37.823 17880-18420/com.example.ofir.bopofinal I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
12-08 13:30:37.823 17880-18420/com.example.ofir.bopofinal I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2
12-08 13:30:37.873 17880-18420/com.example.ofir.bopofinal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000011/n/armeabi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already configurated your api with your package name you can see how to this [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup.)

Because you error is about the api key on the developers console on google.

Answer (score 1):

You have to defined  google Map APi Key in generated **res/values/google_maps_api.xml**

Refer this link to create Map Api Key  and follow Mentioned simple steps 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup